# Simulate external page request in php in my local server

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have written code in a php file that gets called from Paypal when a charge is processed (also called as PIN/API etc.). Paypal sends some parameters, may be many get and post variables etc. too along with the page call using which I send email to customer based of the user details, amount etc. from the parameters. Is it possible that I can save all the call info by any line of code in the php file so that I can simulate same call again, because Paypal sandbox is very time consuming and if I can debug by code locally instead of writing a log code on each step and transferring the php file on server for testing after each code change, then it will save many hrs.

I hope I am clear in my question. I just want to simulate a page request which third-party server is calling and I don't know their parameters. So, I was thinking may be there is a way to do an exact page request by any mean on my local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know which parameters Paypal will be sending you, it's in their documentation. But I can understand you might want this for debugging or error reporting.

**How to capture input**

To capture a request it's usually sufficient to capture `$_GET` and `$_POST`. In some cases you will want to read from `file_get_contents("php://input")` as well but I don't believe PayPal uses that.

**How to make a request**

If your request is simple you can just do a `file_get_contents("mypage.php")`. If you want to send `POST` parameters as well: make a stream context with [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create). Or chicken out and use curl :P